# Execute maven goal without a project

Tags: java, maven

I have some automation that uses `mvn` to download artifacts to a local filesystem so they can be used outside of maven.  Basically, I do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn dependency:get \
    -DgroupId="my.group.id" \
    -DartifactId="$1" \
    -Dversion="$2" \
    -Dpackaging="war" \
    -DremoteRepositories="http://my.repo/nexus/content/repositories/foo"
```

The problem (and its not *really* a problem) is that I get the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building some-other-project 1.2.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I happen to run this from a sub folder of `some-other-project`.  This is confusing to the person running this script as the `dependency:get` execution does not actually build the project.  Short of capturing and processing the output to strip that info, is there a simple way to tell `mvn` that it is just running a goal without an associated project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suppress all `INFO` output by passing `--quiet` flag (or `-q`).

If you'd like to have some `INFO`'s while dropping the rest, you can identify all the components you'd like to silence by doing searches against [Maven github](https://github.com/apache/maven) and [configure the logging properties](https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html) to exclude those.

E.g. you can add the following flag: `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger=ERROR` for that `Scanning for projects...` message.

Comment: I want the `INFO` information in order to let my users know that _something_ is happening (given that the download could take a while if the artifact is large).  Just don't want it to _lie_ about what its doing...

Comment: @Lucas updated the answer with that case / logging.properties

Comment: Wow!  perfect.  Thank you much!

Answer (score -1):

If there's a `pom.xml`, it'll always be used; it could contain extra information for the maven-dependency-plugin. So no, there's no option to ignore this `Building ...` message. Even trying to refer to a non-existing pom-file ( `-f no-pom.xml` ) doesn't help, because Maven now assumes this file exists.